# How to convert this to arff or excel?

Tags: json, excel, weka

{
"Time":"2017-06-06T00:00:00.032083",
"Measurements":[-126, -125, -125,  -126, -126, -126]}
{
"Time":"2017-06-06T00:00:00.259549",
"Measurements":[-129, -131, -131,  -130, -130, -129]}

Comment: What do you mean?  Excel and arff are file formats, and not something you convert a string into.

Comment: this is a json database,and I need to put it on weka,but it's a large file so I need to convert this json file to xcel or arff

Answer (score 1):

Read the file using a Json library (e.g., [Google's gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [minidev](https://www.minidev.net/)) and then create a `weka.core.Instances` object which you can save as ARFF (see Weka wiki article on [Creating ARFF file](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/creating_arff_file/)).